# Snap.svg error when passing a Snap.animation to Element.animate

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate, snap.svg

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evg3v/3/) shows the bug I am facing. Is it really a bug or am I doing something wrong?

In the fiddle, hover both circles, the white one is properly animated and the black one disappears and an infinite loop is starting to throw errors in the console.

```
var animateCircleIn = Snap.animation({
    r: 15
}, 400, mina.backout);

var animateCircleOut = Snap.animation({
    r: 10
}, 400, mina.easein);

var paper = new Snap("svg");

// Bigger black circle that does not work, see the console
var c2 = paper.circle(60, 60, 30);
c2.hover(function () {
    console.log(this.animate);
    c2.animate(animateCircleIn); // Infinite loop of errors
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its a bug you have discovered, in the source it looks like for a duration its looking at 'easing.dur' and not 'attr.dur', you can prove this by setting this in your object...

```
animateCircleIn.easing.dur = 400;
animateCircleOut.easing.dur = 400;
```

and it will work.

Highlighted in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evg3v/4/) here with it working. So I think you will have to do an odd workaround like above, or change the snap.svg.js source to match. (I'll see if I can get an update to github)

I think in snap.svg.js, ms = easing.dur; should be ms = attrs.dur; unless I'm missing something about how its set.

(git pull request was done, I think this is fixed in 0.4.1)

Comment: I'll take care of the bug report and the pull request if you want, it would be my first and an easy one.  But as we both have done a part of the job I let you decide if you want to take care of it

Comment: Thanks, I did this earlier (actually I'd missed the pull request which you've just made me think of). Oddly it was my first attempt too! https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/pull/180 not sure if I did it right though :)